# Jasper Report Bands When No Data Source

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My understanding is that if you don't supply a `JRDataSource` to the `JasperFillManager`, then the resultant JasperReport will not contain any detail bands.

For reasons outside the context of this question, I want to place a few components (bar chart, and a table) on a small/simple JasperReport, and I want the data to come from a HashMap that I'll pass in. Thus, I don't need a JRDataSource implementation, which also means I won't get any detail bands.

So my question is: **then what band(s) should I be adding my components to?** The detail band is where I would normally add components to, but if I don't get a detail band, where does these orphaned components go?

**Edit:** Tangential to this question would be the obvious: how would I then calculate the size (height) that this band would need to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `JREmptyDatasource` to the `JasperFillManager`. You can even specify how many virtual records you want, i.e. how many detail bands will be displayed, using the `JREmptyDataSource#JREmptyDataSource(int count)` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in the Title or Summary band.

In effect your report will have no data. But since you're passing in a Map as a parameter with "data", then you are happy with this data-less report. Be sure the report is set to show "All Sections, No Detail" when there is no data.

With a chart you just set the chart height and band height however you want. A table component will expand... but that's not a problem. It can expand the Title or Summary band as needed.

Comment: I would avoid putting your content into a Title or Summary band because that would ruin the semantics of those bands. I prefer using Giorgos' answer of passing a `JREmptyDataSource(1)`, which would give you a single detail band.

Comment: That's a fair point... but I was thinking that his chart probably does belong in the title or in the summary semantically. The detail band prints once for each record in the data set. He has no records, so it's reasonable to have no detail band. Passing a data set of 1 empty record and pretending there is a data set in order to have a detail band doesn't seem more satisfying to me.